# D365CE - Copying customization and structure from Production to a new sandbox

Tags: sandbox

ENVIRONMENT:
We have been using D365CE about 1.5 years and have found it go be quite good.

```
Our previous CRM was Microsoft Dynamics 2016 onPremise                          
                            
While using D365CE, a traditional setup was used                            
    Name            Type            
    Development         sandbox         
    Playground          sandbox         
    Production          production          
                            
Our solution was:                           
    Developed in the DEV environment                        
    Tested in the PLAY environment                      
    Deployed in the PROD environment
```

PROBLEM:
This worked well for months, until we went live.
Once live, the size of the PLAY and PROD environments swelled until we
routinely exceeded our assigned storage capacity.

```
The temporary fix was simply delete the PLAY environment, since most of the                             
development work was already done.                              
                            
This brought us back under the storage capacity limit.                          
                            
Unfortunately, the DEV environment has kept growing and contains:                           
    Database        2.5 GB              
    File        7.8 GB              
    Log     0.0 GB              
                            
With this increase in size, we can no longer create an additional sandbox for testing,                          
without exceed our storage capacity again.                          
                            
                            
Additionally, the DEV environment has become corrupted:                         
    Several custom fields are missing which had been added to standard tables.                      
    Other fields have had their display name 'blanked' out.                     
    A form has a custom field included which is missing from the database
```

ANALYSIS:
Regardless of the cause, our current Development sandbox is corrupted.
Fortunately, the Solution we developed is unmanaged, and was imported in Production as such.

```
We have retained the ZIP file copies of each Version as it was exported.                            
                            
Further Development work is required, as well as ongoing maintenace, to the deployed solution.
```

SOLUTION:
A new Development sandbox is required.

```
We understand that it is possible to copy the structure and customizations only from                            
Production to a new sandbox.                            
                            
This new DEV1 sandbox would be used for further development work, to be exported to the                             
Production environment as an unmanaged solution.
```

QUESTION:
Will this work?

```
Can you copy the customizations and structure from a Production environment to a                            
new sandbox, then modify the copied solution, and export it again to the original                           
Production environment.                         
                            
Please keep in mind:                            
    There is only one internally developed solution involved                        
    The solution is unmanaged.
```

CONCLUSION:
Thanks for reading this far.

```
Any feed back or ideas would greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic, as it's not a programming question. This seems very specific to Dynamics (e.g. product support question). Also, please be mindful of tags: none of the tags you used applies to Dynamics. Lastly, if you decide to post a programming question, please be concise and be sure to format properly. It's helpful to read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]